# Android: Umano AndroidSlidingUpPanel Sliding two Panels?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slidingmenu, android-sliding

So I started using Umano's AndroidSlidingUpPanel library and it's very useful. I managed to implement ONE sliding panel from the bottom which worked very well. However I want to implement two Sliding panels (top and bottom) such as this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECEC"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

            <com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview
                android:id="@+id/picture_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout><LinearLayout>
```

How do I add two Sliding Panels to a view? :)

Comment: Do you find any solution please let me know

Comment: Use this instead: https://github.com/drxeno02/androidprojects-book2-slidingdrawer

Answer (score -1):

try  to set the parameter `rotation = "180"` of

com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview